# Kotlin class MediaPlayer

Tags: android, kotlin

Надо сделать приложение для прослушивания аудио потока, а сам до этого только на PHP программировал. В Kotlin'е дуб. Из документации к классу MediaPlayer на сайте https://developer.android.com/ взял код воспроизведения и повесил кнопку, которая при нажатии запускает функцию Play и воспроизводит аудио.
Код:

```
fun Play(view: View) {
   val url = "http://175.198.19.102:10999/music" // your URL here
    val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer().apply {
        setAudioAttributes(
            AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                .build()
        )
        setDataSource(url)
        prepare() // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
        start()
    }
    
}
```

Теперь не знаю, что писать в функции Stop. Чтоб останавливать эту музню... Помогите, пожалуйста...

Comment: Там же в той же  документации все есть.

Answer (score 1):

Вынесите ссылку `val mediaPlayer` за пределы методов. Например:

```
lateinit var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer

fun Play(view: View) {
    val url = "http://175.198.19.102:10999/music" // your URL here
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer().apply {
        setAudioAttributes(
        AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
            .build()
        )
        setDataSource(url)
        prepare() // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
        start()
    }
}

   // Тут добавляете методы stop()
fun stop(view: View) {
    mediaPlayer.stop()
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!!! Работает как надо))